# How to insert multiple data into 2 tables in database using jquery asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYMTy.png)This are my database and code:

[image]

If I register, only student table contain and section table nothing change. Please help me? Thank you.

```
    function SignUp() {
        $("#ShowModal").modal();
        $("#message1").hide();
        $("#message2").hide();
    }

    function SaveForm() {
        var name = $("#user").val();
        var pwd = $("#Password").val();
        var email = $("#Email").val();

        if (name=="" || pwd=="" || email=="") {
            $("#message1").hide();
            $("#message2").show();
            return false;
        }

        var data = $("#Registration").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            data: data,
            url: "/Register/SaveData",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#message1").show();
                $("#message2").hide();
                $("#Registration")[0].reset();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your registration form view at least, pls?

Comment: Can you show us your controller action `SaveData` ?

Comment: @Serge I uploaded my registration form. Go to my picture above sorry stackoverflow cant allow me post my code here so I do screenshot

Comment: @NagibMahfuz I uploaded my registration form above. You can look at it

Answer (score 0):

Rather than serilizing the form, you can create a json object and pass it.

```
var data = $("#Registration").serialize(); without using this,
```

Create your own Json object with form data. Something similar to below. Your Student model class should have the slimier structure as the Json object.

```
 var data = {
    Username: $('#studentName').val(),
    Password: $('#Password').val(),
    Email: $('#Email').val(),
    ..
    ..
    Section: {
        Id: $('#SectionId').val(),
        SectionName: $('#SectionName').val(),
        GradeLevel: $('#GradeLevel').val(),
    }
}
```

**#Added Model Classes**

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string SectionId { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }

    public Section Section { get; set; }
}

public class Section
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SectoinName { get; set; }
    public string GradeLevel { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to submit form and use ajax in the same time. You have two ways

1. Add Model to your view and remove onclick java script code
2. Remove type="submit" from the view

Comment: sir do you have some time to check my code? i'll send you rar file.

Comment: Just remove "type=submit" and try again